# 2 different outcomes when summing an array descending and ascending

Tags: python, floating-point, precision

I am not sure why I am getting two different results in Python when I sum an array sorted in ascending and descending fashion. Descending gives me the exact number.

```
    def alg_sum(x):  # x == x[:n]
    s = 0.
    for x_i in x:  # x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1}
        s += x_i
    return s

N_1 = [0.3 + 0.2 + 0.1]
N_2 = [0.1 + 0.2 + 0.3]
print("N_1:", alg_sum(N_1))
print("N_2:", alg_sum(N_2))
N_1: 0.6
N_2: 0.6000000000000001
```

Comment: @NielGodfreyPonciano Not really. I understanding the rounding with floating points but why is it accurate when it is descending?

Comment: Neither result is exact.  It's just rounding differently.  None of the values you're adding, nor their sum, are exactly representable as floating point values.